# Minified library using Web Essentials having trouble

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2010, web-essentials

Currently working on a angular app where I have my application specific angular modules under folder **`App`**.

Using Visual Studio extension - **Web Essential 2012**, created a javascript bundle file for local angular modules and related files(controllers, directives, services) into `app.all.js.bundle` files under **`App`** folder.

Structure looks now like :

[image: Bundle file]

Now, when I use `app.all.js` into my `index.html` application works fine for me, however when change to `app.all.min.js, I am getting following error:

> **Uncaught Error**: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…0g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59405%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)                        angular.js:38

when using `app.all.min.js` I am switching `angular.js` to `angular.min.js`.

Do I need to do anything more?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are injecting the dependency service and controller properly.

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```